# What Git '--progress' flag is for and how to use it

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Today I have noticed in my IDE (IntelliJ) that when I do 'commit and push' from the IDE level I can see in the version control output tab that IntelliJ is using the following command:

```
git push --progress origin storyBranchA:storyBranchA
```

I wonder how I can use that 'progress' flag outside of my IDE, is there any nice usage explained somewhere as I cannot find anything about that flag, and why the IDE is actually specifying the branch to commit to as `storyBranchA:storyBranchA` and not simply

```
git push --progress origin storyBranchA
```

Regards
Kris

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [man page for `git push`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) seems to have documented the flag:

> `--progress`
>
> Progress status is reported on the standard error stream by default when it is attached to a terminal, unless `-q` is specified. This flag forces progress status even if the standard error stream is not directed to a terminal.

Since IntelliJ is not launching the program under a terminal, it’s asking Git to report the progress anyway.

The reason for specifying both the local and remote refspec on the `git push` command line is that they never optimized for the case when both sides are the same.  `storyBranchA` is equivalent to `storyBranchA:storyBranchA`.  It is possible to have the branch named one way locally, and another way remotely.  In that case, you'd see something like `storyBranchA:someOtherRef` on the command line.

You also don't want to just use `git push` blindly because their settings may have `git push` setup to push all tracking branches, rather than the single branch that was intended.